# How can I fix the issue with my custom font not displaying properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a custom font for my website, the first font that I used works although the second one doesn't seem to work. I am not sure why. I imported both fonts using the @font-face rule but just isn't working for some reason on the second font I imported.

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sanji's Kitchen</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landingpage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <h1 class="title">Welcome to Sanji's Kitchen</h1>
        </div>
        <img class="image-centered" src="pixleonepiece.png" alt="Sanji Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <h2>Did you like the food?</h2>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes">
            Yes
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no">
            No
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="content-options">
            Leave a review: <input type="text" name="text-field">
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="content-options">
            Date: <input type="date" name="selected-date">
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@font-face {
    font-family: day dream;
    src: url(fonts/Daydream.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: pokemon;
    src: url(fonts/pokemon_pixel_font.ttf);
}

.title-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: day dream;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;

}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content-container {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 60%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: pokemon;
}

.content-options {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content-options input {
    margin-top: 10px;
}


body{
    background-image: url(SSF2_Thousand_Sunny.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: pokemon;
}
```

The font that isn't working is the pokemon one. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried re-writting the whole website again.

Comment: did you check the real name of fonts? isn't "pokemon pixel"?

Comment: Do you have a 404 error in console specifically on the pokemon font, or the font is just not applied to your dom elements ? If it's the second case, maybe some child elements are overriting the font-family propety in their css. In this case try using this :

`body, body * {
    font-family: pokemon;
}`

Here you will force all elements inside the body to apply the correct font.